# Angular 2: Input binding

Tags: angular

I want to bind the value of variable to input after the `ngOnInit` but in my case it is binding to the default value that is initialised before.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'myapp',
  template: `{{test}}  `
})
class App {
  @Input() test;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  directives: [App],
  template: `
    <myapp [test]="test"></myapp>
  `
})
export class parent implements OnInit{
  test:string='i dont want this value';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.test="I am after ngOninit";
  }
}
```

I want "I am after ngOnInit" to be printed but in my case it is "i dont want this value" is printed. 
Here is the plunker code : http://plnkr.co/edit/c4wR1X740wtHaFjvuPXW?p=preview
How can i achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you setting a default value if you don't want a default value?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Default value is just for initialization. In real case it is empty.

Comment: @Amir is the issue not solved?

Comment: @echonax Not yet solved. I am using angular version 2.4.1 so using onInit() as you suggested is showing me error.

Comment: @Amir If you are using 2.4.1 then can you reproduce the plunker with it?

Comment: @Amir I've updated my answer with a 2.4.1 plunker it's working fine.

Comment: @echonax What could be other reason? I am stuck on this problem. Please suggest some thing that might have wrong in my solution.

Comment: @Amir I have given you a plunker that works. It can't be the same setup. Analyze the plunker and your code, try to find the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated as OP said it should be a 2.4.1 version plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TLj9Ta4rv64Esi2uFwTP?p=preview

Your `ngOnInit` function is never called.

Since you are using the alpha version of angular2, lifecycle hook names are different.

```
onInit() {
      this.test="I am after ngOninit";
  }
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eDs2hjNydBoQBYWaKUZN?p=preview

Alpha.47 Breaking Changes: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-24